# How to change IDA's name representation programmatically?

Tags: ida, idapython

I've made a custom loader and processor. As I use segment to separate something, now I want my name automatically shows in the following form
`9     dseg_1234      the same as 2, but without data type specifier`,
which is described in https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/609.shtml
The Java processor and loader can change the name representation to number 9 without any additional settings. However I failed to find any code relating to changing the name representation :(
So how does the Java processor change this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_inf_attr`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/285.shtml) with the `INF_NAMETYPE` index